# Swap as image positions with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have the following script that I put together with part of another, what I need is to change the images by dragging the red heart to the blue one, the blue takes the place of the red and vice versa.

Today the trawler wipes out the old ones.

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

        <img id="drag2"
             src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mirella-gabriele/valentine/256/Heart-red-icon.png"
             draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50px">
    </div>

    <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

        <img id="drag1"
             src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/mirella-gabriele/valentine/256/Heart-blue-icon.png"
             draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="50px">

    </div>
```

Javascript:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {

ev.preventDefault();
var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();

    var id = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    var element = document.getElementById(id)
    var div = document.getElementById(id).parentNode;
    var clonedHeart = document.getElementById(ev.target.id).cloneNode(true);

    ev.target.parentNode.insertBefore(element, ev.target.id.nextSibling)
    document.getElementById(ev.target.id).remove();
    div.appendChild(clonedHeart);

    ev.dataTransfer.clearData();
}
```

I hope this help you.

Comment: Could you please give a brief explanation of your solution?